# RHEL- mysql installation error

Tags: linux, rhel

I am trying to install mysql in my RHEL 5.6 machine. I use the command `yum install mysql`. However, I receive the below error message.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.el5.remi.i386
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.el5.remi.i386
```

I did the commands `yum remove mysql` and removed `/usr/lib/mysql` folder itself. However, I receive the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on these error messages it looks like you might have mixed packages from different repositories.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.el5.remi.i386
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.el5.remi.i386
```

I'd be inclined to remove the non-Remi related packages, and to also make sure that you're only installing packages from the Remi repository that are related to MySQL going forward.

I would also need to see more output regarding what MySQL related packages, if any, are still installed.

```
$ yum list mysql\*
```

Comment: I am using RHEL and I am logged in as root only.

Comment: I used the rpm package from the mysql website, instead of using the yum command to install the db. Now I do not have any error.

Comment: @Ramesh - OK, was it the self contained server with all the dependencies included then?

Comment: yeah, it had all the rpm packages in a tar format. I un-tarred the items and did rpm -ivh for all the packages.

Comment: @Ramesh - OK, I've used those before as well, glad you were able to resolve the issue!

Comment: @slm One little addendum on your point about being careful about which repo's you install from: The [priorities yum plugin](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) is a helpful way to try to ensure that all things being equal one repo's packages will be preferred over another. That said, conflicting with base channel packages seems like an issue with the repo maintainer. That has to cause a lot of problems for them to build their RPM's that way. I can see 3rd party repo's conflicting with each other but base channel seems like a fairly obvious reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Remove package mysqlclient and simply install mysql only.
Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into an issue where you can't just uninstall mysqlclient15 because of other packages depending on it (or rather depending on what it provides).  You can use yum shell to work around that by creating transactions.  This allows you to remove mysqlclient15 and install mysql-server at the same time, so libmysqlclient is always provided.  I have trimmed the output of the commands below to improve readability.

```
root@dev5:~ # rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysqlclient15-5.0.92-3.ius.el5
root@dev5:~ # yum shell
> remove mysqlclient15
> install mysql-server
> run
> quit
root@dev5:~ # rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9
mysql-server-5.0.95-5.el5_9
```